# VueJS - Remove empty divs from DOM after fetching data

Tags: vue.js

I'm having problems with rendering some data fetched from an API. Even though the data is empty using the v-if condition, empty divs are in the DOM.

```
<template>
 <div class="product" v-for="products in jsonData" :key="products.title">
  <div class="product-item" v-if="products.city==city||city=='all'">
   <div>{{products.title}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>



<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Product',
  props: ['city'],
  data() {
    return {
      jsonData: ''
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/data/products.json'
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        this.jsonData = res.data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);

      })

  }
}
</script>
```

Since v-for has a higher directive than v-if, I can't seem to find a solution to completely remove empty divs.

For example, if *products.city == 'Seattle'*, it renders the products available in Seattle. But in the DOM, all products are being loaded, so the classes for *.product* are being stashed in the DOM.

Thanks, appreciate the help.

Comment: The div that contains the loop will be the child element. Move your v-if to the top div and get rid of the middle one

Comment: @Mark what MarianKlühspies said sounds right but one point, you cannot put all your logics inside your view. Another point,  It is better to move your axios inside the vuex store .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on answer above, so i open another answer.

The jsonData.filter is not a function is probably throwed by default jsonData value which is string, string is not an array, so .filter is undefined. If jsonData supposed to be an array, default value of jsonData should be declared as empty array.

Btw, to achieve what u want, you can use computed of vue to filter data u want, then use the computed filteredJSONData to render.
Below is the code.

```
<template>
 <div class="product" v-for="products in filteredJsonData" :key="products.title">
  <div class="product-item">
   <div>{{products.title}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Product',
  props: ['city'],
  data() {
    return {
      jsonData: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredJsonData() {
      return this.city==='all' ? this.jsonData : this.jsonData.filter(
        products => products.city===this.city
      )
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/data/products.json'
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        this.jsonData = res.data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're amazing man.

I also stored the axios in vuex module, so its cleaner now, and its working like a charm.

Didn't know how powerful computed parameter is...

Thanks again Hong!!